# Elasticsearch - Point alias from OLD_INDEX to NEW_INDEX

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-7

I have an alias which is pointing to my OLD_INDEX. I have a requirement where I am creating a new index and after creation I need to point my alias A to the NEW_INDEX. I need to do this in `Java.`

I have looked almost everywhere but I cannot find any java implementation for this.

Would really appreciate some help. If possible, it would be great to have a sample code as well.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you get a chance to check the below answer

Comment: hey sorry, the requirements changed yesterday. I no need to do the re-indexing. Though thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Refer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-aliases.html)

You can add7remove an alias.

To remove,
`POST /_aliases { "actions" : [ { "remove" : { "index" : "test1", "alias" : "alias1" } } ] }`

To add an alias,

`POST /_aliases { "actions" : [ { "add" : { "index" : "test1", "alias" : "alias1" } } ] }`

[List of supported actions](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-aliases.html#indices-aliases-api-request-body)

You can use java low or high level clients to do this. [Refer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/current/index.html)

You have to initialize Rest client and make a call by using above Json requests and end points.